# Identity Server 4 /connect/token return 400 Bad Request when using grant_type:refresh_token

Tags: identityserver4, access-token, refresh-token

I'm using Identity Server 4 as the Identity Provider for an Anuglar SPA. The application authenticates and authorizes fine, however, randomly we encounter an issue where the logged user is suddenly kicked out, well within the token lifetime. When we inspect the network logs, we realized that the `/connect/token` endpoint with the `grant_type: refresh_token` returns a 400. So my assumption is that when the application tries to get a new token using the refresh token, the operation fails.

Following are the client details for the FE application:

```
  [AllowOfflineAccess] = true
  [IdentityTokenLifetime] = 300,
  [AccessTokenLifetime] = 3600,
  [RefreshTokenUsage] = true,
  [AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime] = 2592000,
  [SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime] = 1296000,
  [RefreshTokenExpiration] = true
```

Like I said, this behavior is random, so we can't pinpoint why it's happening.

Any thoughts?

Attached a screenshot of the network log showing the error:[image]

Comment: Could be that one of the cookies involved expires? or that there is  duplicate requests for the refresh token (if you use on-time-refresh tokens), if so you might get logged out?

Comment: @ToreNestenius you might be correct- the network log shows two subsequent token requests. Do you have an idea why it happens? or how to troubleshoot it? I've attached a screenshot.

Comment: see my answer below, how do you ask for new refresh tokens?

Comment: We are using angular-oauth2-oidc library. The library handles the token refresh, I need to look in to details on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that one of the cookies involved expires? or that there are duplicate requests for the refresh token (if you use on-time-refresh tokens) if so you might get logged out.

If you see duplicate requests, that depends on how and what library (if any) you use to request new access tokens.

The other option if you can't solve it, is to disable one-time refresh tokens in IdentityServer (RefreshTokenUsage). see https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/tokens/refresh/

Comment: I'm marking this as the correct answer because you pointed me in the right direction about duplicate requests for the refresh token. As it happens, we have registered the 'setupAutomaticSilentRefresh()' call from the library inside a component, instead of the appcomponent where the authService was registered. Once I fixed that, the random logout issue seems to be gone.

Comment: Great! Glad you solved your problem!